# Importing DWG into QGIS loses points

Tags: qgis, import, dwg

I want to import a DWG file into QGIS (3.8.1). I do this via Project > Import/Export > Import Layers from DWG/DXF.

Everything works fine, the imported data looks almost like the original DWG - with one difference. All CAD layers which only contain points are not imported. I first thought, this might be because I ticked the option to "merge layers" (so i got only 4 layers "hatches", "texts", "lines" and "polylines" as result). 
Importing the data to another geopackage without merging layers did not change the issue - in the layer overview in QGIS of the DWG the point layer exists, and i have checked it to import it's data - but it does not show up in QGIS in the resulting group.
Any ideas why this is happening and how to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by points?  Are they generic AutoCAD points or blocks or are they Civil 3D COGO points?

Comment: uhm, i m fairly unexperienced with CAD. We use TrueDGW Viewer (Autodesk). how can i figure out the nature of the Points?

Comment: Any chance you can upload a sample of your data?